# Is there class/library/framework to call web service in SWIFT language in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, swift, ios8

As we found there is many library and classes are available to hande web service calling in `Objective-C`.

Now I need to same thing for `SWIFT` language from which i can call web service with GET or POST request.

Is there any such library/framework which will help to `SWIFT` developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello SWIFT iOS Developers,

I have RnD about other class/framework but I am not satisfy on that.

So I had created my own customized class named [iHelperClass](https://github.com/iChirag/iHelperClass) to call web-service in `SWIFT` iOS.

It is purely in `SWIFT` languages.I created it very normal way so easily understandable.

Hope it helps you guys!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) would probably be the most popular one for the foreseeable future, written by the folks behind [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).